# Typescript Abstract and final React Component interface type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface ReduxState<TReduxState, TConnectedStateProps, TConnectedDispatchProps, TOwnProps> {
    connect: (
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<TReduxState,TConnectedStateProps>,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToProps<TConnectedDispatchProps>
    ) => (component: React.ComponentClass<TConnectedStateProps & TConnectedDispatchProps & TOwnProps>) => any;
}
```

The important bit here is the last line `component: React.ComponentClass`

In a container, I do this:

```
// Define state here
const state: ReduxState<...> = new State...;

state.connect(
    (state)  => {
        return {

        };
    },
    (dispatch) => {
        return {

        };
    }
)(SomeComponent);
```

This works fine when `SomeComponent` is a final class, i.e.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<Props, State>
```

However, it does not work if my class is abstract:

```
abstract SomeComponent extends React.Component<Props, State>
```

I get

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof SomeClass' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'ComponentClass'.   Cannot assign an abstract
>   constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

How do I define the type of `component` so it can be both?